# handling unicode encode errors in python

Tags: python, unicode, encode

I'm writing a program to ingest some xml but unfortunately there is some unavoidable bad formatting inside it in terms of character sets, the xml is labelled as utf-8 but im not sure i can trust that. I would be happy to just ignore errors but for some reason the method i would expect to work is not working and throwing errors. Here's a character I've copied from a utf-8 labelled xml file and the error:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
foo = ' '

print foo.encode('utf-8', errors='ignore')
```

-

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 4, in <module>
    print foo.encode('utf-8', errors='ignore')
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc2 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

specifically I'm getting errors from a lot of white space characters and I cant diagnose the problem, I also cant seem to get `ord()` to work on this mystery character to find out what it is so I'm a bit stumped.

I'm using Python 2.7.2

UPDATE:

the character I pasted here gets converted to a space, heres a pasteb

http://pastebin.com/sP4Hb2Pi

Comment: The character you pasted http://pastebin.com/sP4Hb2Pi is a space as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to convert character to ASCII

`unicode(foo, 'ascii', 'ignore')`

If not, here is how to decode without errors

`unicode(foo, 'utf-8', 'ignore')`

Comment: in the production code i get the following error when i try the second option:

`TypeError: decoding Unicode is not supported`

Comment: in the end i used `unicode(foo, 'ascii', 'ignore')`, worked a charm

Answer (score 0):

`foo` is already in utf-8, as it is a byte string and you have declared that encoding.

You mean `foo.decode('utf-8')`.

Comment: in the production code doing this throws the following error: `UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xa0' in position 616: ordinal not in range(128)`